# What are hashes (#) used for in the library's source?

Tags: haskell

I was trying to figure out how mVars work, and I came across this bit of code:

```
-- |Create an 'MVar' which is initially empty.
newEmptyMVar  :: IO (MVar a)
newEmptyMVar = IO $ \ s# ->
    case newMVar# s# of
         (# s2#, svar# #) -> (# s2#, MVar svar# #)
```

Besides being confusingly mutually recursive with `newMVar`, it's also littered with hashs (#).

Between the two, I can't figure out how it works. I know that this is basically just a pseudo-constructor for mVar, but the rest of the module (most of the library actually) contains them, and I can't find anything on them. Googling "Haskell hashs" didn't yield anything relevant.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

They're (literally) magic hashes. They distinguish GHC's primitive's like addition, unboxed types, and unboxed tuples. You can enable writing them with

```
{-# LANGUAGE MagicHash #-}
```

Now you can [import](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/GHC-Exts.html) the stubs that let you use them with

```
import GHC.Exts

unboxed :: Int# -> Int# -> Int#
unboxed a# b# = a# +# b#

boxed :: Int -> Int -> Int
boxed (I# a#) (I# b#) = I# (unboxed a# b#)
```

This actually is kinda nifty when you think about it, by wrapping the magical and strict primitives like this, we can handle lazy `Int`s and `Char`s uniformly at the runtime system level.

Because primitives are not boxed, they're segregated at the kind level. This means that `Int#` doesn't have the kind `*` like normal types, which also means something like

```
kindClash :: Int# -> Int#
kindClash = id -- id expects boxed types
```

Won't compile.

To further elaborate on your code, `newMVar` includes a call to a compiler primitive in GHC to allocate a new mutable variable. It's not mutually recursive so much as a thin wrapper over a compiler call. There's also some darkness gathering at the corners of this function since we're treating `IO` as a perverse state monad, but let's not look to closely at that. I like my sanity too much.

I don't use primitives in everyday code, nor should you. They come up when implementing crazy optimized hotspots, or near primitive abstractions like what you're looking at.

Comment: Thank you. So for my purposes in understanding library snippets, I can essentially ignore them and just think about the types that they're associated with?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Pretty much, yeah.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I would say so, you can read the documentation for the primitives if you're really curious, I don't think you'd gain a ton from them however.

Comment: Thanks. And would it be possible for you to elaborate on the "thin wrapper" comment? I don't understand. As I see it, it involves 2 functions that call each other without any terminating cases. Why doesn't it loop forever? Is there something built into GHC that specifically handles MVar, which makes the code behave differently then "it should"?

Comment: @Carcigenicate, `newMVar` and `newMVar#` are *different functions*. `newEmptyMVar` calls `newMVar#`, not `newMVar`. As for the wrapper thing, basically there's a primop, `newMVar#`, and then a little wrapper function, `newEmptyMVar`, that does boxing and unboxing and calls the underlying primop `newMVar#` to do the real work.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I wish I could double vote/accept.

Comment: @Carcigenicate As for documentation, the primops are not all documented very well (if at all), so you sometimes have to guess based on name and type signature. By the way, one of the main reasons GHC uses these wrapper things is that in many cases, it can actually *erase* the wrappers during optimization, producing very efficient code.